# How to give points to user based on number of characters on post description in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal-7, content-management-system, drupal-modules, userpoints

I have installed the User points, rules and related modules. How to give points to user based on number of characters on post description? Example:- A user will get only 0 point for posting / replying a forum thread, if the description part has bellow 150 characters. 1 point has to be awarded if it is above 300, 2 points if it crosses 600 characters, 3 points for 900 characters, 4 points for 1200 characters. The maximum 5 points has to be given for the description which has more than 1500 characters. Is this possible with Drupal?

**If the above is not possible then please help me to do the bellow, I have completed the full website after many struggles and now I don't know how to implement the points system.**

How to give 2 points automatically to users for posting forum response?

How to give 2 points automatically to users for posting forum response? I (Admin) also needs the option to change the default points. I have installed the User points, rules and related modules. If just give me a good example then I can implement the procedure to all the sections. I had completed my full website except the points system. Also, the user must needs to see his total points on his dashboard.

Comment: Now I currently setting the rules and what to type on this field "The entity to which this transaction refers." It is asking me to set a Data selector. Example:- Data types: Select data of the type Any entity.

Answer (score 0):

Find API for USer Points module. Find out how to write a Rule programmatically (create a rule that counts the entered fields). Than add this rule: you will need it 'after node is added / saved'. (You wight need to add that node or the node field as an argument to the rule.)